# Conversion failed error when running case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, varchar

I'm getting an error 'conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NO' to data type int' when I run the following case statement. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

```
,CASE
         WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)) > 0
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10))
         WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)) < 0
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10))

          ELSE 'NO'

       END AS DAYS_BEFORE_DUE_DATE
```

Comment: A `CASE` expression can only return one data type, and it uses [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to determine the return data type. For the above, you have some `int` values and then `'NO'`, which is a `varchar(2)`. Obviously `'NO'` can't be converted to an `int` and hence the error. I would suggest returning `NULL`, and if you need to show "no" then handle that in your display layer.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  Converting a date to a string to call as an argument to a date function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can covert the result of the `DATEDIFF` function like this:

```
select CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)) > 0
            THEN convert(varchar, DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)))
            WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)) < 0
            THEN convert(varchar, DATEDIFF(DAY, convert(VARCHAR, Deliveries.DUE_DATE, 10), convert(VARCHAR, DELIVERIES.OB_DELIVERY_DATE, 10)))
            ELSE 'NO'
       END AS DAYS_BEFORE_DUE_DATE
from Deliveries
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7cd823b04e60e40a8c462b0dbe7e8ce)

Comment: Thanks so much. This WORKED! I just love this website with all you smart people out there. Have a great evening!

Comment: Hi @SHELL, you are welcome. Thanks for your feedback. Have a great evening you too.

Answer (score 0):

In `case` statement only one data type can be returned. However You can use **NULL** instead of `NO`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu's comment makes clear, the problem is one of mixing data types in a `case` *expression*. (TSQL does not have a `case` *statement*.)

Guessing hat on: `Due_Date` and `OB_Delivery_Date` might be `Date` columns. If so, you can simply use `DateDiff` to get the difference in days:

```
DateDiff( day, Deliveries.Due_Date, Deliveries.OB_Delivery_Date )
```

Since both `then` clauses return the same value, they can be combined:

```
case when DateDiff( day, Deliveries.Due_Date, Deliveries.OB_Delivery_Date ) != 0
  then Cast( DateDiff( day, Deliveries.Due_Date, Deliveries.OB_Delivery_Date ) as VarChar(3) )
  else 'NO' end as Days_Before_Due_Date
```

Note that `Cast` is used to convert the numeric value to a string.

If you wanted to handle early/on time/late you could use [`Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
case Sign( DateDiff( day, Deliveries.Due_Date, Deliveries.OB_Delivery_Date ) )
  when 1 then 'Late'
  when 0 then 'On Time'
  when -1 then 'Early'
  end as ScheduleStatus
```